# xCode can’t add framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xcode6

I’m trying to add a few frameworks and dylib’s to xCode (6.3 Beta)

> Audio Toolbox.framework
>   CFNetwork.framework
>   CoreGraphics.frameworl

The standard libraries needed for parse.
I have successfully used parse (and imported these frameworks) in earlier projects though xCode can’t seem to “find them” this time. (In my new empty single view application)

I am trying to add these frameworks under

Targets -> Build phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

The external parse (1.2) libraries have been successfully added though the other frameworks will not be autocompleted by xCode.
Do I need to add these libraries by hand from a location from my mac?
How can I find and add these frameworks to my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing xCode Beta worked. No clue why this did work. It isn’t the ideal solution but it is one.